# Check if a buffer's name ends with `.org`

Tags: buffers, parentheses

I want to write a function to check if a buffer is an Org buffer. Here is my attempt.

```lisp
(defun org_bufferp (buffer)
  (if (bufferp buffer)
      ((setq buffer_name (buffer-file-name buffer))
             (if (stringp buffer_name)
                 (if (string-match ".*\.org$" buffer_name) t "nil1")
               "nil2"))
      "nil3"))
```

However, the result surprised me.

```lisp
(org_bufferp '(current-buffer)) ;; => nil, but should be t!
(org_bufferp  (current-buffer)) ;; ===> ERROR! Why?
```

#### Questions

1. Why does `(org_bufferp '(current-buffer))` return `nil`? I don't even assign any `nil` to possible returned values.
2. Why does `(org_bufferp  (current-buffer))` return an error?
3. I'm new to Elisp, and find it hard to deal with the endless parentheses. What would you suggest in order to make the code cleaner?

Comment: Please don't use tag `elisp` for questions about using Elisp. It's for questions about the nature of the language itself, e.g. compared to other Lisp dialects. Thx.

Comment: Your code was syntactically invalid. Added a missing `progn`.

Comment: Thank you @Drew. Your answer is valid,  but I delete `progn` from your edit since that's exactly what I missed. I hope future user can be benefited by this post.

Answer (score 2):

The main ingredient you missed is [`progn`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/progn.html). This could happen to Elisp beginners, who do not yet understand the syntax of `if`.

Here is the correct code. Notice that `progn` evaluates its arguments, and returns the last value.

```lisp
[..]
(progn (setq buffer_name (buffer-file-name buffer))
       (if (stringp buffer_name)
         (if (string-match ".*\.org$" buffer_name) t "nil1")
       "nil2"))
[..]
```

Your original code is invalid. The `car` of that list is evaluated to return a string or nil. Then Emacs tries to invoke that as a function and apply it to the rest of the elements in that list. Error. Again, using `progn` can resolve it.

---

With the edited code, `(org_bufferp '(current-buffer))` returns `nil3`, and `(org_bufferp  (current-buffer))` returns `nil2` or `nil1` if it's not visiting a `*.org` file (`nil2` if not a file-visiting buffer), and `t` if visiting if visiting a `*.org` file.

For `(org_bufferp '(current-buffer))`, the arg is a *list*, `(current-buffer)`, which clearly doesn't satisfy `bufferp`.

For `(org_bufferp  (current-buffer))`, `buffer_name` is either the buffer name, if visiting a file, or `nil`, otherwise.

---

You might really want to check the *major-mode* of the buffer, instead of getting `buffer-file-name` and then checking the file-name extension.  Just do this to your variable `buffer`, once you've determined that its value is a buffer:

```
(with-current-buffer buffer (derived-mode-p '(org-mode)))
```

---

To make code clearer, and help get over the paren-shock of an Elisp newbie, indent the code using `C-M-q` with point at the left paren of `(defun...`.

Comment: Thank you @Drew. I would like to hear more about `(derived-mode-p)`. As far as I know, it does not tell if a given buffer is in a certain mode. However, going through the elisp manual did not help me.

Comment: BTW, it's usually better to test the mode using `derived-mode-p` than by exact comparison. That way, if you're in a mode that's derived from Org mode it still works.